# Best way to implement image saving for an iOS photo gallery

Tags: ios

In my iOS app I would like to give the possibility to save photo obtained from the iPhone camera. I'm undecided how to save these pictures and then show them to you later. From reading the Apple Documentation and other articles, I found three possible solutions:

1. Save image into Documents folder of app
2. In my app i use also core data, so i create an entity with a Transformable attributes where a can save the photos
3. Photo library (this feature is aviable from IOS5)

In your opinion what is the best solution among them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it dependes on what your  application  does ,In your case it is more likely to use Document Directory i suppose . you can also find below guidelines useful  .

- Document directory have advantage of Sandboxing .
- Store file path in core data and image in document directory and use them when needed.
- more easy to synchronize core data and image store in Document directory . Example : deletion of image from document directory and core data .
- **most important** , please see apple ,**ios data usage guidelines** , as some app got rejected because of this

  https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/

  http://www.chrisboyd.net/post/25806584185/icloud-and-the-new-ios-data-storage-guidelines
- Your customers might complain about too much data being backed up to iCloud.
- Remember to not start a big job of moving files on the main thread during app startup. This will get your app killed by the startup timer watchdog.
- if you dont want icloud backup .you have two options :

  1.Put your files in the Cache directory then they won't be backed up and Apple won't reject your app. However, when iOS 5 gets low on space it may delete all the files in there
  2.Put files in Documents but flag them so that they are not backed up. There's a technote (QA1719) on how to do this. This only works in iOS 5.0.1 and later
- you can also see this link for more
  http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/data-management/local-file-storage-in-ios-5

Comment: I believe that i will use the Document directory option to save photo without core data for save path. The photo can be many so i will consider the option of avoiding that the photos are saved in iCloud. Thanks for the reply and suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

First one is best, you can save image into Documents folder of app.